# Source Table Structure Changes in SSIS Data Source

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, visual-foxpro

I am importing a FoxPro table into SQL Server 2008 using SSIS.  The source data is a proprietary database that I have no control over.  Let call the table I am importing Customers.

Sometimes, the structure for Customers looks like this:

**ID (int)**

**NAME (char(30))**

**ADDRESS (char(30))**

**CITY (char(20))**

**STATE (char(2))**

**ZIP (char(10))**

**CCNUM (char(16))**

Other times, it looks like this:

**ID (int)**

**NAME (char(30))**

**ADDRESS (char(30))**

**CITY (char(20))**

**STATE (char(2))**

**ZIP (char(10))**

**CCPTR (char(100))**

This proprietary database basically has 2 different versions of the database.  The older version had a field called CCNUM (credit card #) that was a basic 16 character field.  The newer version replaced that field with a field called CCPTR, which was a 100 character field that represented a card pointer (encrypted value for the actual credit card number).

The problem here is everytime I have to switch back and forth between 2 datasets that have these different table structures, SSIS blows up and I have to go in and manually refresh the metadata.

My question is, is there anyway I can have SSIS dynamically look for one of these fields at runtime, and based on which one is there, load the correct data into the correct table structure in SQL?

Forgive me if this has been asked before.  I am still fairly new to SSIS and I tried searching for this answer but to no avail.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. SSIS expects that there are no significant changes to the meta data of its source and destination components. There are ways to programatically influence this with .NET, but that kind of misses the point.

A well-designed solution to this problem is to create 2 separate data flows that copy the data into a shared staging table. Use this staging table as source to transform your data and push it to its final data structure.

Answer (score 0):

if you build your package based on the lenght (100) and tun it on the (16), you should get only a warning. Are you getting an error?